# Pick the child dates closest to parent dates

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

[image]

Rules for picking the children to parent:

1. Parent can have 0 to any number of child
2. Children pay date always lesser than the parent dates
3. When opening any parent the child dates must be closest to parent date
   eg:
   If I choose Batch #2 (28-Apr-2023) the expected child record is only 27-Apr-2023, though other child records are applicable should not pick because parent exists in #1 26-Apr-2023

[image]

How to write in an C# LINQ Method? Appreciated your time and value your suggestion. Thank you

Comment: Too much unspecified. How many childs can a parent have (min and max)? What are the rules for ranges (e.g. in your example, why is 21-Apr applied to #1 and not #3)? Which parent wins, when a child is exactly between them? If another child 29-Apr is added, should everything be rearranged; e.g. should child 27-Apr move to parent #1?

Comment: Parent can have 0 to many children. The child  pay date must be closest to parent date. 21- Apr applied to #1 because closest higher parent date is Batch #1 26-Ap whereas Batch #3 is 18-Apr which is lesser than child date. The child 29-Apr is invalid scenario cannot come into this can ignore it because the list of children are always less than the parent dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to order the parents and create tuples containing each parent and the next one. Afterwards for each range you have to find all payments within this range ([running example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ynL879)):

```
var parents = new[]
{
    new DateOnly(2023, 4, 26),
    new DateOnly(2023, 4, 28),
    new DateOnly(2023, 4, 18),
};

var childs = new[]
{
    new DateOnly(2023, 4, 22),
    new DateOnly(2023, 4, 25),
    new DateOnly(2023, 4, 27),
    new DateOnly(2023, 4, 17),
    new DateOnly(2023, 4, 21),
};

var parentsOrdered = parents.OrderDescending().Append(DateOnly.MinValue);
var payments = parentsOrdered
    .Zip(parentsOrdered.Skip(1), (batch, limit) => (batch, limit))
    .Select(range => (range.batch, childs: childs.Where(child => range.limit < child && child < range.batch)));

foreach (var payment in payments)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Batch: {payment.batch}");
    foreach (var child in payment.childs)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"   {child}");
    }
}
```